# Could I use "pâtisserie" as "le bonbons" or "le dessert"?

Tags: vocabulaire

Could I say:

> J'ai acheté des gâteaux pour la pâtisserie.

I don't mean here the shop (magasin) but for dessert or comme candy.

Comment: Some already answered to that in your previous question.

Comment: Please take this comment with a healthy dose of non-native salt, but perhaps one way that might **come somewhat close** to using "pâtisserie" like you are suggesting/asking about (i.e., to mean dessert/confectionery course in general [but not so much for candy]) would be in the form of "comme pâtisserie": “Hier, j’ai acheté/fait/servi/commandé des gateaux/un gâteau comme patisserie."

Answer (score 1):

No, "la pâtisserie" is the shop. "J'ai acheté des gâteaux pour la pâtisserie" means only one thing in french: "J'ai acheté des gâteaux pour les mettre dans la pâtisserie".

Comment: It was in the exam of bacc today and the words in brackets was only [ * chez -*de- pour] and i think "de" couldn't be and "chez" too

Comment: As said in you other post the best answer is "de" for this exact sentence.  Even if in France we'd rather say "à".

Comment: This is wrong. "pâtisserie" is not only the shop. It's also the cake.

Comment: "pâtisserie" yes, but "la pâtisserie" is the shop.

Comment: It definitely depend on the context. You can say "La pâtisserie que Jean m'a apportée jeudi était super bonne.", and in this context it's a little cake.

Comment: *La pâtisserie* can also mean the technique for cooking pastry. Ex: *il fait de très bons petis gâteaux, il maîtrise bien la pâtisserie*. But whatever the meaning is (the cake, the shop, or the technique), *j'ai acheté des gâteaux pour la pâtisserie* does not make much sense.

Comment: I know I was talking about the post context.

Comment: @Nek so,  could it be "pour" if w're about to use it as "cake" ?

Comment: @user179312 what do you mean by "could it be "pour""?

Comment: @Nek coul i say j'ai acheté des gâteaux {pour} la pâtisserie,  if pâtisserie means cake ?

Comment: No, "pour" means "for". Your sentence sounds like "I bought cakes for the {cake|bakeries}". As you say "pâtisserie" means "cake". So you can say "j'ai acheté des pâtisseries".

Answer (score 1):

No.

"Pâtisserie" means either "the bakery", the practice of baking, or "the baked good". The phrase would be translated to English as "I bought cake for the bakery" which is grammatically correct but does not have the meaning you're looking for.

From reading your context in the comments, your setup was to choose the right word for

> "J'ai acheté des gâteaux **X** la pâtisserie."

where X can be one of {chez, de, pour} and have meaning

> "I bought cake **from** the bakery"

For this situation, "de" would have been the correct answer.